# How do I extend a jQuery type with new function?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, javascript-objects, jquery

I have a special type object which is really QTip2. I want to add an extra function to my qtip type so I can do something like this with my instance:

```
myQtip1.doSomething();
```

How do I extend functions on my jQuery objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    my_function: function () {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Then you can use it like

```
$('#element').my_function();
```

You can also use it in a chain:

```
$('#element').parent().my_function().show();
```

Comment: What about name conflicts? How do I avoid them if in the 'global jquery' namespace?

Comment: Check out this article for more on namespacing: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.nl/2009/01/namespace-your-javascript-function-and.html

Answer (score 1):

Try adding stuff to `jQuery.fn` -

```
jQuery.fn.myMethod = function () {
  //...
};
```

To differentiate it from other libraries' `myMethod`, you can call it `customPrefix_myMethod` (replacing `customPrefix` with a custom prefix of you own).

Comment: What's the difference between doing this in jQuery.fn or jQuery.fn.extend?

Comment: There should be no major difference, unless one wants to add multiple methods (in which `.extend` would be shorter). However, adding directly to `jQuery.fn` should be negligibly faster, as it avoids calling an extra function.